# Unable to run servlet in tomcat 8.5.15 and eclipse jee neon

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, web

I've followed the tutorial on youtube channel "Java Brains" link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gU0RebsaFzQ&t=10s  and got stuck while running a servlet file . I am getting this error message :

**HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]**

**Type** Status Report

**Message** /SimpleServletProject/servlet/org.altamash.careersix.SimpleServlet

**Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

My  simple index.html is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Simple Web Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml file is as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SimpleServletProject</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>SimpleServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SimpleServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and finally my servlet file SimpleServlet.java is as follows :

```
package org.altamash.careersix;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SimpleServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/SimpleServlet")
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello from doGet method");
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("<h3>Hello in HTML</h3>");
    }

}
```

Please guys Help me to solve this problem :( .. Thanks .

Comment: Run project instead of concrete file.

Comment: whenever i run project , it will execute index.html

Comment: And then you can go to `/SimpleServlet`.

Comment: yeah !!!! It worked :) :) :D ! Thank you so much sir for your help :)